# How to end iteration through a C++ std::set one element early?

Tags: c++, loops, iterator, set

**C++**

I have the following iteration loop:

```
for (it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); ++it) {
    //my code here
}
```

I want to end this iteration 1 element early. I've tried the following but it doesn't compile:

```
for (it = container.begin(); it != container.end() - 1; ++it) { //subtract 1
    //my code here
}
```

How can this be done? Thanks.

Comment: is result->container and container the same thing in your code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can iterate up to one before `std::prev(s.end())` where `s` is your set, taking care of the possibility that the container is empty:

```
#include <iterator> // for std::prev

auto first = s.begin();
auto last = s.empty() ? s.end() : std::prev(s.end()); // in case s is empty
for (auto it = first; it != last; ++it) { ... }
```

**Note**: `std::prev` requires C++11 support. A C++03 alternative is `--s.end()`.

Comment: @bames53 there's not enough context to know if the check is  unnecessary. It should be easy enough to figure out how to remove the check.

Comment: @bames53:  While the decrement will always be safe, since a reversible container has to always allow `std::prev(container.begin())`, if you tried to iterate from the end iterator to one before the end iterator, you will likely hit UB.

Comment: @juanchopanza (Of course I didn't actually downvote, I'm just poking fun at Yakk. What you say applies equally to complaints that code would crash on an empty container; i.e., there's not enough context to know that a check is needed. It's easy enough to figure out how to add one if necessary.)

Comment: @DaveS If the code guarantees by construction that the container will not be empty then there is no likelihood of UB from unchecked decrementing of a one-past-the-end iterator.

Comment: @bames53 aaaah OK, got it. Yeah, of course it goes both ways. I think the answer now contains enough information for OP to do whatever matches their requirements.

Comment: I'm including <iterator> but my compiler is still not recognizing std::prev. What am I missing?

Comment: @amorimluc do you have C++11 support? If not, you can replace the call to `std::prev(s.end)` with `std::advance(s.end(), -1)`.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse CDT on a Linux machine. Neither of these functions are being recognized...

Comment: The error I get: - candidate is:
 - no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘last = std::advance [with _InputIterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<Tuple*>, 
  _Distance = int]((* & last), -0x00000000000000001)’

Comment: @amorimluc seems I was wrong about `std::advance`. Another option is `--(s.end())`. I will update the answer. Are you using GCC? If so, you can tell it to use C++11 with the flag `-std=c++0x`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `std::prev`:

```
for (it = container.begin(); it != std::prev(container.end()); ++it) { //subtract 1
    //my code here
}
```

Comment: It isn't hard to check if the container is empty, to avoid segfaulting.

Comment: @Yakk and the check may be completely unnecessary if the code guarantees that the container is not empty.

Comment: @Yakk I assume the OP can figure that out himself.

Comment: what is 'result' here?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (it = container.begin(); it != --result->container.end(); ++it) { //subtract 1
    //my code here
}
```

`std::set::iterator` is bidirectional, which means you can do `--` and `++` on it. It doesn't meet the requirements for a random access iterator, however, so you can't do `-` and `+` with it.

Comment: @Yakk true, but that's perfectly fine if earlier code guarantees that the container is not empty.

Comment: @Yakk Well then the problem statement doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

`result->container.end() - 1` requires a random access iterator, but you only have a bidirectional iterator. Instead you probably want `--result->container.end()`.

Also you may not want to recompute that every time, although it's not a big deal:

```
for (auto i(begin(result->container)), e(--end(result->container)); i!=e; ++i) {
```

Comment: I like the caching of the end iterator.

Comment: Why/how do you use `end(result->container)` instead of `result->container.end()`?

Comment: Why: stylistic preference; How: the standard library provides this function and it's found through argument dependent lookup, or we can explicitly write `std::end(result->container)`

Answer (score 0):

A c++98 solution to find last iterator can be

```
set.find(*set.rbegin())
```

Another option though it is undocumented and not recommended by people

```
it!= --set.end()
```

Also works, its behavior should be undefined when set is empty (begin == end)